# Indenting Objective-C literals with Xcode

Tags: xcode, indentation, auto-indent, objective-c-literals

Xcode think that this:

```
NSArray *persons = @[
    @{
        @"name": @"Bob",
        @"pet": @"cat"
    },
    @{
        @"name": @"Alice",
        @"pet": @"dog"
    }
];
```

would be better indented like so:

```
NSArray *persons = @[
@{
@"name": @"Bob",
@"pet": @"cat"
},
@{
@"name": @"Alice",
@"pet": @"dog"
}
];
```

Can you teach Xcode about indenting Objective-C literals?

Is there another alternative?

**Note:** I already know I can "force" indent with <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>opt</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>, however this **will** go away when copying/pasting and will not fix the problem.

Comment: All formatting goes away when copying/pasting unless you "paste with style", doesn't it?

Comment: @user1118321 Yes, except it's called `Paste and Preserve Formatting` and the keyboard shortcut is opt+shift+cmd+V

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a bug with http://bugreport.apple.com.

If you also submit it to OpenRadar, people outside Apple can read it. I can point you at this bug report about your specific issue: http://openradar.appspot.com/12394453

The more people who report this problem, the more priority Apple will give it.

Comment: Just copy-and-pasted a new bug report against Xcode 4.6. *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 5 auto-indents like this:

```
NSArray *persons = @[
                     @{
                         @"name": @"Bob",
                         @"pet": @"cat"
                         },
                     @{
                         @"name": @"Alice",
                         @"pet": @"dog"
                         }
                     ];
```